# When I try to run it the program crashes and I don't know why

Tags: c, function, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I want to return in my function the `n` - size of the matrix - and the matrix itself at `*p`.

The file is something like, for example,

> 3 
>  
>   10 
>   20 
>   30

this is how I call it:

```
main( )
{
    int n, *p;
    n = Load_Matrix( p );
}

int Load_Matrix( int **ptr )
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i, a, n;
    fp = fopen( "matrix.txt", "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Cannot load file\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    fscanf( fp, "%d", n );
    *ptr = (int *) malloc( sizeof(int) *n );
    for ( i = 0; i<n; i++ )
    {
        fscanf( fp, "%d", &a );
        *( ptr + i ) = a;
    }
    fclose( fp );
    return n;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%d",n);` --> should be `&n`. `Load_Matrix(p);` --> should be `&p`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, such errors are caught *by the compiler* with a bit of optimization and cranking up the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing the address of the passed pointer ptr, instead of the pointer itself.

The line `*( ptr + i ) = a;` is wrong. It should be `(*ptr)[i] = a;`

Also pass the address of the pointer in main

```
int n, *p;
n = Load_Matrix( &p );
```

And the line `fscanf( fp, "%d", n );` is wrong. fscanf() need an address of n.

And a number of small errors are still present, like function prototype for Load_Matrix(), int main( void ), check all return values

Comment: this one solved me other problems too.. bad this is actually an exercise at my college and it say not to use at all this [] so how can i rewrite this (*ptr)[i]=a;

Answer (score 0):

this :

```
 n=Load_Matrix(p);
```

should be

```
n=Load_Matrix(&p);
```

as `Load_Matrix` expects to get pointer to pointer.
also this

```
 fscanf( fp, "%d", n );
```

should be

```
  fscanf( fp, "%d", &n );
```

Comment: @user3420365 `fscanf(fp,"%d",n);` should be `fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);` (you need to apply the address of operator to `n`)